# Why does the die of a desktop CPU need to be so small?

Tags: cpu

The amount of space on the PCB would allow for the die to be much larger and would make designing it much easier, what is the reason for this?

Comment: This question is really unclear. How are you proposing the extra die area could be used? Empty space, routing on the die, extra logic (for example larger caches)? What part of the design process are you imagining you can simplify?

Comment: Presumably if you used a bigger die you could use an older (cheaper) process. Then the next cost saver is cutting design time by reusing previous masks. Care to buy 20 million pentium II's I just made?

Answer (score 8):

Cost is proportional to die size, so for that reason the die is usually optimized to be as small as possible to meet the performance requirements.

The number of die you can get per wafer is extremely important in a high cost process like those used for desktop computers.

There are other reasons as well, like routing very high speed signals, but cost is the main driver.

Comment: I would think for a desktop CPU, the largest driver would be high speed signal routing and power efficiency, not cost.  There are multiple ways of reducing cost (such as increasing wafer size), but there are physical problems with large die sizes.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, increasing wafer size is not easy. The transition from 200 to 300 mm required the whole semiconductor  equipment industry to retool; I can't even estimate the dollar cost, but  $billions is way too low. The next transition (450 mm has been proposed) will likely be even more costly.

Comment: And increasing wafer size doesn't help to reduce the number of dead chips, which is a major cost for state-of-the-edge manufacturing. IIRC one of the Henessey & Patterson books has a good chapter on the issues involved.

Comment: @ThePhoton: It isn't initially cheap, but does pay off (lots) later. [It helps drive costs down](http://www.intc.com/releasedetail.cfm?ReleaseID=309716&ReleasesType=&wapkw=300mm+wafer).

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen: Correct, large wafers don't increase yield.

Comment: Number of die/wafer is extremely important no matter the wafer size.  If your competitor can produce more die/wafer than you with equivalent performance they win, as they can sell them at lower cost than you can.

Comment: @AndrewSpott - When any defect will kill a die, for a defect rate other than zero, the number of good dies per wafer is inversely proportional to size of the die. Take the limiting case, a die size equal to the wafer size. Then, on average, a defect rate of 1 per wafer will produce (on average) no good dice.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: that is making a lot of assumptions about the defect rate that I don't think you can make:  That defect rate is proportional to die size is *not* necessarily true, defect rate is related to feature size as well.  Defect rate is also *likely* independent of dies per wafer, so your limiting case argument is a little silly.

Comment: @JohnD: True, but you can increase dies per wafer in two ways: increasing wafer size or decreasing die size.  I'm saying that decreasing die size has other drivers than just cost.

Comment: @AndrewSpott Absolutely, there are other drivers than cost, though I would rank cost first because working in the semiconductor industry I hear about it all day long and it's certainly where management focuses.  Die shrinks for cost reduction, etc..

Comment: @AndrewSpott, but if I'm designing a chip today, I can't just say "Well, let's use a bigger wafer to reduce costs". Even Intel can't do that. They need to wait for all their suppliers to bring up the new technology, and that means waiting until enough other ODMs want that bigger wafer size to justify developing it.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, do you have any idea how much does it cost to "increase wafer size"? Are you in the field of theoretical physics or something?

Comment: @AliChen Someone read my profile :).  I am aware:  yet Intel has done it a whole bunch of times.  It is expensive, but so is decreasing feature size (which is how you decrease die size for a roughly equivalent processor).  Currently, I would place the cost of getting smaller features at higher than getting bigger wafers considering Intel's problems with the former.  But I'm a theoretical physicist, so what do I know ;)

Comment: @AndrewSpott, as a matter of fact, the die size cannot decrease and has been stabilized in last years at about 1 cm^2, due to many reasons: competitive performance, necessary I/O pad count, thermal limits, while intra-die variations and near-zero voltage tolerances becoming major obstacle these days, and chemical kinetics is conveniently omitted from management speaks.

Comment: @AliChen: Interesting.  They must be using more dead space on the die in order to shrink the process but keep the die size the same, or adding more transistors to do the same.

Comment: No, there are no dead space. The space is occupied by bigger caches, tune-up elements, security layers, built-in debugger networks, disabled re-configurable features, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yield!

Defects are unavoidable on a wafer. Imagine that a number of darts are thrown at it during the production process. Where they hit, it fails. Larger square dies are more likely to be hit, so you get fewer usable chips per wafer. Newer process suffer more of the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, making more unusable areas.

If the chip has large regular structure on it, you can sometimes work round this by disabling parts of the chip. More often used on GPUs, which have bigger dies anyway.

Comment: This is making an assumption that yield is proportional to area.  I would think instead that it would be proportional to area over feature size:  or something like "feature number".  I.E. one transistor out of a million fails.  If this is the case, decreasing die size (and keeping transistor count constant) doesn't help you with yield.

Comment: Yield is indeed proportional to area. If you get a particle on your wafer, the chip it lies on dies. Twice the area, twice the fails, BAM.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: No.  If you get a particle on your wafer that is larger than the feature than the feature dies (not always the chip...).  If you get a particle on your wafer that is smaller than the feature, then the feature might not die.  So, you need to discuss particle size compared to feature size.  You can also have issues with stochastic processes like chemistry.

Comment: I am not so convinced. Can you provide some source with a thorough explanation?

Comment: @AndrewSpott The assumption that yield is inversely correlated to area in an assumption well supported by decades of data. See http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/ice/cd/CEICM/SECTION3.pdf in particular, figure 3-13 on page 3-8. It's intended to demonstrate how defects/cm^2 dropped over time, enabling larger dice to be feasible, but also does a great job of illustrating how smaller dice at the same defect rate improves yield percentage. And that increased yield percentage is compounded by the fact that a smaller die means you can fit more of them on a wafer.

Comment: @8bittree the table above that figure is my point.  The figure keeps feature size consistent, but if you change from a large due to a smaller die and keep the processor the same, then the feature size changed, and the relevant figure of merit is not defects as a function of due size but defects as a function of feature size.

Comment: @AndrewSpott Table 3-12, in which only 3 of 6 have more defects at smaller features sizes and 2 of 6 processes actually have *fewer* defects at smaller feature sizes? That's a much weaker correlation than 100% of smaller dies having a higher yield than larger dies. And when the defect rate does rise, it appears to do so at about the same rate that the feature size decreases. So even if yield percentage remains constant, you still profit from a smaller die because you have more per wafer.

Comment: @AndrewSpott To be fair, yes there are factors other than die size that affect yield. **But all other things being equal, a smaller die results in a greater yield.**

Comment: @8bittree: **and you can't downsize the die size of a CPU without changing the feature size or the processor transistor layout.**  Period.  It doesn't matter if "all other things being equal, smaller die results in greater yield", because you can't keep everything else equal.  You are also extrapolating from a 1996 plot, see my next comment for a source more current.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=DYX5AVBYwKgC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22defect+density%22+processors+vs+feature+size&source=bl&ots=w9MVMIl2ch&sig=768VZtQdPJe5stFg-BEjnOZhbAg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ-qP_lqHPAhWG24MKHUgsAuMQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22defect%20density%22%20processors%20vs%20feature%20size&f=false) is a google books link that talks about "kill ratio" as a function of defect size over feature size, it also has a nice figure on page 27 that shows yield for constant architecture as a function of process size.

Comment: @AndrewSpott A 1996 plot that just happens to be built on 3 decades of data. Do you have reason to believe there's been a recent change? Also, from your google books link, page 27: "...[baseline yield] for a uniprocessor with constant architecture increases from 85% at 250nm to 93% at 50nm. ...because the gain from the rapidly decreasing chip area outweighs the increased susceptibility to yield loss due to the higher kill ratio."

Comment: woo, I couldn't imagine this would lead to such a fuzz. I guess there's material for a good question.

Answer (score 3):

> what is the reason for this?

I can't say for sure that what I've answered is *the* reason but it's a pretty significant one...

So if you just made everything bigger by 2, parasitic or gate capacitances would double in value and speed performance would halve at high speed. Power consumption at high speed would also double because of the number of times per second each gate capacitor is charged and then discharged - this energy is totally lost.

Capacitance is proportional to area so double the dimensions, quadruples the capacitance but, of course the thickness to the substrate would double and this halves the value of C.